# Adding an existing framework with different architecture in two different target in xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, target

I have a framework. It has simulator's architectures as well as device's. When we try to upload our code appstore it did not allow and error summarises to remove simulator archs from the framework. Then we run lipo command to remove simulator archs. Now we have two copies of frameworks.

1. MyFramework.framework (with out simulators archs)
2. MyFramework.framework (with all archs)

I thought of creating two targets one with a framework without simulator's archs and another with all archs.
But as both frameworks are having same name in the bundle, Xcode always considering the framework without simulator's archs. So I'm unable to run it in simulator?

Any suggestion on how to add different architecture frameworks in different targets?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using the lipo command to create separate versions of the framework, I would recommend using this script to remove unneeded architectures during a buid:

```
APP_PATH="${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${WRAPPER_NAME}"

# This script loops through the frameworks embedded in the application and
# removes unused architectures.
find "$APP_PATH" -name '*.framework' -type d | while read -r FRAMEWORK
do
FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME=$(defaults read "$FRAMEWORK/Info.plist" CFBundleExecutable)
FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH="$FRAMEWORK/$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME"
echo "Executable is $FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"

EXTRACTED_ARCHS=()

for ARCH in $ARCHS
do
echo "Extracting $ARCH from $FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME"
lipo -extract "$ARCH" "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH" -o "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-$ARCH"
EXTRACTED_ARCHS+=("$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-$ARCH")
done

echo "Merging extracted architectures: ${ARCHS}"
lipo -o "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-merged" -create "${EXTRACTED_ARCHS[@]}"
rm "${EXTRACTED_ARCHS[@]}"

echo "Replacing original executable with thinned version"
rm "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"
mv "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-merged" "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"

done
```

If your framework file came packaged with documentation, etc., it's possible some version of that script is already included in there for you. (That was the case for me when I ran into this problem.)

- Add that script as a .sh file in your project
- Add a "Run Script" phase in your target's build phases after the "Embed Frameworks" phase. (Mine is currently the very last phase).
- Set the "shell" line to `/bin/sh`
- Set the command to `/bin/sh <path to the script file>`

Now you will be able to run on a sim and submit to the store without issue.